# How do I edit an Access report on the fly?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

This seems like it would be pretty simple, but I’ve been googling my brains out for the last two weeks and I can’t find the answer.  I'm using Access 2010...

I have a form with a button that the user clicks to get a report, that button pops-up a form that ask for the date of the requested report and then the report open with the correct info.  The problem is I need to manipulate the data before it is displayed.  Some of it I’ve done directly through the SQL statement and some through the Control Source of the text boxes on the report.  But some of the data is a little more complicated… I need to extract certain text from a “remarks” field (memo) and I need to concatenate a few fields together separated by a comma, some of which may be blank.  I know I can use the “+” to do that as in “lastName & (“,” + firstName) which will eliminate the unwanted trailing comma… but what if “lastName” is blank… I will be left with an unwanted preceding comma???

How do I loop through the data as it is being “written” to the report so as to edit it “on-the-fly”?  I don’t want the user to edit the data because I want to get the exact same results every time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You posted two questions here. I will post a solution to the first, but you should submit two posts - one for each question.

Answer (score 1):

This an answer to the first question (but what if “lastName” is blank):

```
lastName & IIf(Len(Lastname) > 0, ",", "") & firstName
```